# How to check the number of Ble devices that can connect with an Android Phone

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Each phone can connect a limited number of Ble devices, how do I know how many Ble devices one phone can connect to

Thanks All

Comment: This is stackoverflow not "howtosolveallyourproblems", so please put your code that is not working and we'll try to help you. You can search for guides about "how to list BLE devices".....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no API for this in Android. There is actually not an API for this at the HCI level. Keep your number of connections low or expect errors when you try to connect too many devices.